Conditionally filter results of query based on a single flag
I have a simple table with two fields -- an ID field (Primary Key, INT), and a PartNumber field (VARCHAR). What I'm trying to do is conditionally filter down to the part numbers that begin with either "C" or "E" if a specific expression is set to 1, otherwise show all rows. Is this possible? I've provided code below to better demonstrate my question:
/* Set up sample table */
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #TestTbl

CREATE TABLE #TestTbl (ID INT PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
                       PartNumber VARCHAR(100))


INSERT INTO #TestTbl (ID,
                      PartNumber)
SELECT t.ID,
       t.PartNumber
FROM   (VALUES (1, 'A11111'),
               (2, 'A12341'),
               (3, 'B12232'),
               (4, 'C11111'),
               (5, 'E99999'),
               (6, 'A10101'),
               (7, 'L99999'),
               (8, 'T49390')) t(ID, PartNumber)
                
/* Make sure I can query it...and this also represents the results I want if the expression is not set to 1 */
SELECT t.*
FROM   #TestTbl t

/* This query represents the effect of what I would like if the expression is set to 1 */
SELECT t.*
FROM   #TestTbl t
WHERE  t.PartNumber LIKE 'C%'
       OR t.PartNumber LIKE 'E%'

/* This is my attempt to limit to PartNumbers that start with "C" or "E" in a way that requires me to change only one value.
   This doesn't work. Instead 1 returns all rows and 0 returns no rows.*/
SELECT *
FROM   #TestTbl t
       CROSS APPLY (SELECT FilterFlag = IIF(t.PartNumber LIKE 'C%' OR t.PartNumber LIKE 'E%', 1, NULL)) ca
WHERE  (CASE
          WHEN ca.FilterFlag IS NOT NULL AND ca.FilterFlag = 1 THEN 1
          WHEN ca.FilterFlag IS NULL THEN 1
          ELSE 0
        END) = 1 /* I would like to be able to toggle this "= 1" between 1 and 0.
                    1 would show only PartNumbers that start with "C" or "E" and 0 wouldn't apply the filter at all and therefore show all rows */

There may be another way to approach this but ideally this would be done in a single query and there would only be one value I would have to change to apply/not apply the filter (preferably at the end).
Thanks in advance!

While asking a question, you need to provide a minimal reproducible example:
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements.
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL.
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).
All within the question as text, no images.

You need to explain what your if a specific expression is set to 1 is.

This can be solved by creating two sets of data, where one set is all and other is the filtered one.
SELECT *
FROM   #TestTbl t
CROSS APPLY (
        SELECT  t.*, 0 AS FilterFlag
        UNION ALL
        SELECT t.*, 1
        WHERE   t.PartNumber LIKE 'C%' OR t.PartNumber LIKE 'E%'
    ) x
WHERE  x.FilterFlag = 1 -- or 0

This works but looks a bit "weird" in my eyes. Usually, for such filters, it's more easier to just do:
SELECT *
FROM   #TestTbl t
WHERE  (t.PartNumber LIKE 'C%' OR t.PartNumber LIKE 'E%') OR @someParameter IS NULL

Since you often use a parameter to create your filter condition.

This is the exact type of thing I was looking for. Thank you!

You overcomplicated it - you don't need a CASE expression, just simple AND/OR logic.
Also returning a FilterFlag of null just added to the complexity.
DECLARE @ToggleFlag bit = 1;
  
SELECT *
FROM #TestTbl t
CROSS APPLY (SELECT FilterFlag = IIF(t.PartNumber LIKE 'C%' OR t.PartNumber LIKE 'E%', 1, 0)) ca
WHERE @ToggleFlag = 0 OR ca.FilterFlag = 1;

You don't even need the CROSS APPLY
SELECT *
FROM #TestTbl t
WHERE @ToggleFlag = 0 OR t.PartNumber LIKE 'C%' OR t.PartNumber LIKE 'E%';

Note: @ToggleFlag = 0 can be replaced by any expression you desire - it doesn't need to be a variable.

You don't even need the @ToggleFlag = 1 part. WHERE @ToggleFlag = 0 OR t.PartNumber LIKE 'C%' OR t.PartNumber LIKE 'E%' should work, or even WHERE @ToggleFlag = 0 OR t.PartNumber LIKE '[CE]%'.

I was hoping to not have to separately declare/use a variable. That’s why I wanted it all in one query.

You said I would like to be able to toggle this "= 1" between 1 and 0. - how do you plan to do that without a variable? It should be trivial to avoid the variable, once you explain what should be used instead.

@MikeS - As DaleK mentioned in the last line of the answer, you can replace @ToggleFlag = 0 with whatever you need. If you are directly modifying the SQL, you could toggle between WHERE 0 = 0 ... and WHERE 1 = 0 .... You could even CROSS APPLY (SELECT x as ToggleFlag) T ... WHERE T.ToggleFlag = 0 ...

You can solve this using a nested IIF function in the where clause:
declare @flag int =1
;with your_data as (
SELECT t.ID,
       t.PartNumber
FROM   (VALUES (1, 'A11111'),
               (2, 'A12341'),
               (3, 'B12232'),
               (4, 'C11111'),
               (5, 'E99999'),
               (6, 'A10101'),
               (7, 'L99999'),
               (8, 'T49390')) t(ID, PartNumber)
)select * from your_data
where iif(@flag=1 and (partnumber like 'c%' or partnumber like 'e%'), partnumber, iif(@flag <>1, partnumber, ''))=partnumber;

